# Insert slide number and total count between navigation arrows of owl carousel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, owl-carousel

I have an ngx owl carousel in my angular application with configurations as below:

```
const carouselOptions = {
 items: 1,
 dots: false,
 nav: true,
 navText: ["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"]
};

<owl-carousel [options]="carouselOptions" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme','row','sliding']">
 <div class="item" *ngFor="let imgUrl of imageList; let i=index">
     <img src={{imgUrl}} alt="image slide" />
 </div>
</owl-carousel>
```

I have altered the default navigation arrows into custom arrows by using the navText key inside the owl carousel options. What I need is a way to inject the slide numbers as `(current slide)/(total slide count)` in between this navText arrows of owl carousel.

I tried to check the documentation but they dont have the option to add the step numbers as 1/7 between the navigation arrows.
I have implemented it in a angular application and would like to know a suitable solution to achieve using typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one idea)))
First of all let set custom html container for our navs (arrows):

```
const carouselOptions = {
 items: 1,
 dots: false,
 nav: true,
 navText: ["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
navContainer: '#my_nav_container'
};
```

Create this div after carousel and create there div with counter:

```
<div id="my_nav_container">
 <div id="slides_counter">
  ..your counter code here..
 </div>
</div>
```

owlCarousel prepend prev arrow and append next arrow to the div by default and you get what you want)))

And even by CSS you can set order for elements inside `my_nav_container` by flex properties:

```
#my_nav_container {display:flex; justify-content:center;}
#my_nav_container .prev-slide {order:1}
#my_nav_container #slides_counter {order:2}
#my_nav_container .next-slide {order:3}
```